# Facebook payments API - Error with no code

Tags: javascript, facebook, payment

I am implementing the Facebook payments API and receiving an odd error dialog with no populated data, it basically looks as follows:

```
An error occurred, Please try again later.
API Error Code:
API Error Description:
```

The javascript returns a null object in the callback.

JS implementation:

```
FB.ui({
    method: 'pay',
action: 'purchaseitem',
product: 'http://localhost:8000/PRODUCT_URL',
},
function(data) {
console.log(data);
});
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Found the error: Seems like the product value was incorrect - whether thats because its hosted locally i'm not sure but it worked when I used a valid product from Facebook's 'Friend Smash' example.

Hope this helps someone